# Combining separate tags in beautiful soup for find methods

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have some html tags that I've selected in Beautiful Soup based on some criteria. I'd like to be able to do further queries (e.g. find() or find_all()) on these tags however I haven't been able to find a method that would allow this since they are all separate entities.

Answer (score 1):

I would combine the tags from the beginning.  Combine the initial queries into one by using the ability to pass in a list to the `find_all()` method, and then search on that result.  Here is an example that will return all the links in a table cell, table header, or div:

```
soup.find_all(["td","th","div"]).find_all("a")
```

Link to the documentation about lists: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list

If your initial query is complicated you can bundle it in a function: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function

Answer (score 0):

rather than combining everything in a line, i would prefer to separate them. For example, i would first using find_all() to capture them into a list then use find() to narrow down my search.

```
container = soup.find_all("tag",{"tag class":"tag class name"})
what_i_want = container.find("another tag")
```

hope this helps